# How to initialize value in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have dropdown list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Register.SelectCompany, Model.Register.Company, "Please select")
```

I have model :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Display(Name = "Company name")]
public int SelecCompanyId{ get; set; }

public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList CompanyName{ get; set; }
```

when i try to do this :

```
companyAccount.Company = (ICompany)Company.Find(model.Register.SelectCompanyId);
```

i get an error

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Register.SelectCompanyId' is of
>   type 'System.Int32' but must be of type
>   'IEnumerable'."}

I have also class that is :

```
public class Company: ICompany
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That error occurs because your `SelectList` is `null`. But you code does not seem to match up - the `DropDownListFor()` method binds to property `Register.SelectCompany` but your model only has property `SelecCompanyId` and then the `SelectList` in `DropDownListFor()` is `Register.Company` but your model only has property `CompanyName`

Comment: i get all companies but problem is when i choose one and click submit button i get an error...because companyAccount.Company is a type of ICompany...so i dont know how to initialize that

Comment: It has nothing to do with that. Its because your `SelectList` is `null`. I'm guessing you return the view but have not reassigned the `SelectList` in the POST method (as you did in the GET method)

Comment: yes ...thats it...tnx :)